# PersistentVoumeClaim not binding to PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a bare-metal kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to understand why the claim is not binding to the volume, and i don't understand.

This is the volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: main-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  local:
    path: /data/mongodb
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - ip-172-31-68-214
```

this is what I see in describe pvc:

```
Name:          xxxx-services-1-mongodb
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
               app.kubernetes.io/instance=xxxx-services-1
               app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
               app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
               helm.sh/chart=mongodb-9.1.1
Annotations:   meta.helm.sh/release-name: xxxx-services-1
               meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    xxxx-services-1-mongodb-5547c455ff-mhznt
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  3s (x62 over 15m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Comment: Add the pvc yaml. There is no capacity and accessmodes specified in the pvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue: there a requirement for 8Gi capacity. I thought that it will be described in `describe pvc` but no, only in the yaml...